# Trouble in MVVM with listbox refreshing

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

Ok, learning MVVM drives me mad. I know it's good pattern, I know, but sometimes...

I have simple book cataloging app. Model done with EF code first. It contains two tables `authors` and `books`. Now, I have `MainWindow` with `MainWindowViewModel` behind it. In MainWindow I have a Listbox bound to ViewModel like this:

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle1}"
ItemsSource="{Binding Authors, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
DisplayMemberPath="Fullname"Name="AuthorsListBox" sSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

Where "Authors" is `ObservableCollection<Author>` in my DataContext (ViewModel). Everything seems fine for now. What is wrong is:

I'm opening new window, simple as hell, only two textboxes and button to create new author

After validation I click the button and new Author entity is saved to database. Then, I close `"CreateAuthorWindow"` and back in `MainWindow`.

There is new no entity showing in listbox. And I can't get it show! Everything in my model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Is there any way to do this without refreshing by hand? (which actually doesn't work either...)

Comment: Are you sure you have added the new author into your ObservableCollection?  Put a handler on that collection's INotifyPropertyChanged and and pop up a message box to check whether that event fired and what property name it fires on.

Comment: I believe ObservableColleciton should fire INotifyPropertyChange event on the "Count" and "Items" properties if the collection is being altered.

Comment: @Stephen Chung - not quite; it actually fires a NotifyCollectionChanged event, as per my answer :)

Comment: When you run it in Visual Studion in the debugger open the Output window and look for data binding errors - sometimes it's surprising what mistakes you can make.

Comment: @IanR, I don't think data binding uses the CollectionChanged event from the INotifyCollectionChanged interface.  It uses the PropertyChanged event from the INotifyPropertyChanged event which ObservableCollection also implements.  Not sure about item collections though -- it may also act on INotifyCollectionChanged.

Comment: @IanR, seems that data-bound item containers also listens to the CollectionChanged event from the INotifyCollectionChanged interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After validation I click the button and new Author entity is saved to database. Then, I close "CreateAuthorWindow" and back in MainWindow.

Saving the new Author to the database will not be enough, you will need to either A) reload Authors from the database or B) add the newly created Author object to the existing list.

Comment: You're right. I thought that ObservableCollection will stay synchronized with database and it's not. I've done it via Messenger class from MVVM Light toolkit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get the new Author to show up in the list box, you need to make sure:

- The DataContext for the `ListBox` is set. If you have set your ViewModel as the DataContext of the View then that will be fine.
- The `Authors` property must be public, and must raise a NotifyCollectionChanged event when the collection is changed (items are added or removed). An `ObservableCollection<T>` will do this for you.
- The new author object you create gets added to the Authors collection. This should raise the `NotifyCollectionChanged` event, and the View should refresh.

If you are doing all these things and still not seeing the new item turn up, check for binding errors in your debug window.

If it's still not working, you may need to post some code...

Comment: You also need to make sure that you do modify the Authors collection on the UI thread.